# NTFS Permissions Anomaly

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have this scenario:

Server-A\Share-A\Folder

Folder permissions are:
Inheritance enabled
Domain Users (group) - Full Control - Inherited from Server-A\Share-A - Applies to This folder only

Server-A\Share-A

Domain Users group is not present.

I cannot remove the Domain Users group from the folder level as it is inheriting from the share. How is the group appearing at the folder level when it isn't present in the level above?

Comment: Folders do not inherit permissions from shares.

Comment: Ours do when inheritance is turned on, or at least that's what it says.

Comment: Each share points to a folder, you need to distinguish between the permissions on the share and the permissions on the folder the share points to.  If you Remote Desktop (or otherwise log in interactively) on the server, what are the permissions on Folder's parent?

Comment: Well, the permissions on the folder match more closely the Windows "share" than they do the folder on the NAS which the share points to, however, the anomaly exists between the folder and the Windows shared folder.